# System V init service can't recongnise mongod

Tags: linux, services, mongodb, mx-linux, system-v

I have been following [official guide](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-debian/) for installing mongodb but it wont run as a service.
When i try

```
$ whereis mongod
mongod: /usr/bin/mongod /etc/mongod.conf /usr/share/man/man1/mongod.1.gz
```

but step from the guide for starting the service

```
$ sudo service mongod start
mongod: unrecognized service
```

Comment: Check  **/etc/init.d/mongodb** or  **/etc/init.d/mongod**  and /etc/rc0.d ... /etc/rc6.d symlinks are exists. Also check service --status-all output and mongodb-org.deb content.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks that you can't install *mongodb-org-server* package **if you don't have systemd** even though there is section about configuring it post install on mongodb docs. In order to make it work I downloaded package from theirs [download center](https://www.mongodb.com/try/download/community?tck=docs_server) for my distribution and found and analyzed the service script.

`ExecStart=/usr/bin/mongod --config /etc/mongod.conf`

So **in order to run server** just ensure that you have folders from your *mongod.conf* and *mongod.conf* itself. You probably have those after failed installation but even if you don't you can create folders and take *mongod.conf* from downloaded archive. By default folders they are **/var/lib/mongodb and /var/log/mongodb** use this command to create them if they don't exist and location for *mongod.conf* is */etc/mongod.conf*

`sudo mkdir -p /var/log/mongodb /var/lib/mongodb`

Also you have to ensure that user who is running has **permission to access folders**. If that is not your current user, then put that user instead of `whoami`

`` sudo chown `whoami` /var/lib/mongodb /var/log/mongodb/ ``

Now you can run your server manually with

`mongod --config /etc/mongod.conf`

Here is the whole *mongod.server* from archive if anyone is interested

```
[Unit]
Description=MongoDB Database Server
Documentation=https://docs.mongodb.org/manual
After=network-online.target
Wants=network-online.target

[Service]
User=mongodb
Group=mongodb
EnvironmentFile=-/etc/default/mongod
ExecStart=/usr/bin/mongod --config /etc/mongod.conf
PIDFile=/var/run/mongodb/mongod.pid
# file size
LimitFSIZE=infinity
# cpu time
LimitCPU=infinity
# virtual memory size
LimitAS=infinity
# open files
LimitNOFILE=64000
# processes/threads
LimitNPROC=64000
# locked memory
LimitMEMLOCK=infinity
# total threads (user+kernel)
TasksMax=infinity
TasksAccounting=false

# Recommended limits for mongod as specified in
# https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/ulimit/#recommended-ulimit-settings

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Answer (score 0):

Check output of `ls /etc/init.d/*mongo*` and `service --status-all`  to find out exact service name

**You** must know what init system used in your system.

Googled for you:

https://wiki.debian.org/Init#Determining_the_init_system

From your link (https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-debian/):

> Recent versions of Linux tend to use systemd (which uses the systemctl command), while older versions of Linux tend to use System V init (which uses the service command).

> You can start the
> mongod
> process by issuing the following command:

> sudo systemctl start mongod

Comment: **I** did checked what system I am using there is a section in the guide I referred to just before the section you just quoted. So that is how I know I am supposed to use ```service``` instead of ```systemctl```  command

Comment: So you should know you may check /etc/init.d/mongod and /etc/rc0.d ... /etc/rc6.d symlinks are installed. Also check service --status-all output and mongodb-org.deb content.

Comment: I did this also there is no service

Comment: So mongodb deb package from mongodb site package do not have these files. I guess it supports systemd only.  Check outpout of dpkg -L mongodb-org. Also why you dont use mongodb from debian repo.

Comment: I finally resolved issue, you can read about it in my answer if you are interested

Comment: Yes, there is no sysv support in this package